# Phonegap will not compile android project

Tags: java, android, cordova

I try to execute phonegap install android but get this error message: an error occured in the android environment. xxx\xxx\platforms\android\cordova\run"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Has anyone had this problem and overcame it? If so how?

---

This was too long to go into the comments

c:\Phone_Apps\MyApp>TREE C:\Phone_Apps\MyApp\platforms

Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 8CA7-78AB

```
C:\PHONE_APPS\MYAPP\PLATFORMS
└───android
├───assets
│   └───www
│       ├───css
│       ├───img
│       ├───js
│       ├───res
│       │   ├───icon
│       │   │   ├───android
│       │   │   ├───bada
│       │   │   ├───bada-wac
│       │   │   ├───blackberry
│       │   │   ├───ios
│       │   │   ├───tizen
│       │   │   ├───webos
│       │   │   └───windows-phone
│       │   └───screen
│       │       ├───android
│       │       ├───bada
│       │       ├───bada-wac
│       │       ├───blackberry
│       │       ├───ios
│       │       ├───tizen
│       │       ├───webos
│       │       └───windows-phone
│       └───spec
│           └───lib
│               └───jasmine-1.2.0
├───bin
├───cordova
│   └───lib
├───libs
├───res
│   ├───drawable
│   ├───drawable-hdpi
│   ├───drawable-ldpi
│   ├───drawable-mdpi
│   ├───drawable-xhdpi
│   ├───layout
│   ├───values
│   └───xml
└───src
    └───io
        └───cordova
            └───hellocordova
```

I lost the original output of the first update I ran it was a huge output with a warning somewhere in the middle.

This is the output that I am getting now:

```
C:\Phone_Apps\MyApp>npm update -g cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/3.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/3.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 node --version
 cordova --version
 cordova create ./MyApp
 pushd ./MyApp
 cordova platforms add android
 cordova build
```

The first line simply verifies you have NodeJS installed and the cordova cli for NodeJS installed globally.

If you don't have NodeJS, you'll need that.

If you don't have cordova:

```
     sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Leave out the `sudo` part if you are using Windows.

Comment: Everything worked except for the last command I got the error message:[Error: An error occurred while building the android project. '"c:\Phone_Apps\My
App\platforms\android\cordova\build"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you run `TREE "c:\Phone_Apps\My App\platforms"` and copy the output?  The `cordova build` command is trying to invoke a shell (batch) script named `build` (or likely `build.cmd` on Windows).

Comment: I had to answer above the output was too long for this box.

Comment: I noticed the error message `"c:\Phone_Apps\My App\platforms\android\cordova\build"` has the wrong path.  The "My App" part should be "MyApp", right?

Comment: No, I think that was just a bad copy job on my part. What's strange is that there is no build subdirectory, or .bat file under  cordova. Same thing with run as well.

Comment: Very odd.  I wonder if your cordova-cli is corrupt.  Maybe try `npm update -g cordova` to update to the latest cordova-cli?  Also, any chance your command prompt has an autorun script enabled?  There will be a registry setting at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` or 
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` if you have autorun enabled.  I've seen cmd.exe autorun scripts cause serious headaches that are elusive to debug.

Comment: The autorun script does not seem to be enabled, I updated cordova but am still getting the same error as before. I am attaching the output of the update above.

Comment: I found a cordova bug with failed builds when spaces are in the name of the project: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4148 .  Still, it's very odd that you don't have the "platforms\android\cordova\build" script.  I'm going to try above on a Windows machine and see what happens.

Comment: @SteveJansen , I too am facing the same error `[error] An error occurred while building the android project.'....phoneGap\mupdf-viewer-master\platforms\android\cordova\build' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.` I have the `build` file present in the folder. Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: `'....phoneGap\mupdf-viewer-master\platforms\android\cordova\build'` not found is because of using some prebuilt project from someone else and some files are actually missing like `build.bat` etc. .merging the cordova folder with a standard one worked.